# How to install .deb file in ubuntu using terminal?

Tags: installation, command-line, google-chrome, deb

I am trying to install Google Chrome,for that I downloaded a google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb file.

When I try to install using `install` in terminal

`sudo install google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb`

It gives following error.

`install: missing destination file operand after ‘google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb’
Try 'install --help' for more information.`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Either you can install using terminal as previous answers say,

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

Or else, You can **double click the downloaded .deb file** and it will be opened in **Ubuntu Software Center**(If you are using ubuntu). Then you can install it clicking on **install** button.

Comment: I got `Package libappindicator1 is not installed.` . So I have to download all dependencies too offline, if I am not having network on the target machine?

Answer (score 4):

You can install it using the `dpkg` command:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

Check `dpkg --help` for more information.

Comment: I got `Package libappindicator1 is not installed.` . So I have to download all dependencies too offline, if I am not having network on the target machine?